# What is the maxium replication rate of Couchbase XDCR

Tags: benchmarking, couchbase

We are currently using Couchbase for data caching and there is talk of doing cross-data center replication with it. However, we will need up to 1000 documents replicated to multiple locations every second. Documents will be between 2 and 64K each.

Is there anyone out there with XDCR experience who can tell me whether this is even feasible, or if we will have to use other means to replicate this data at that speed. The only "benchmark" in the documentation at Couchbase implies that the rate of XDCR is only about 100TPS. (149 ms to replicate 11 documents.)

Answer (score 2):

The replication rate of XDCR is limited by network bandwidth and latency first, then CPU and disk IO. Assuming you have enough bandwidth between the datacenters and your clusters are provisioned properly, Couchbase will replicate hundreds of thousands of documents per second, or more. It's a pretty simple experiment to run, just set up XDCR between two singles node clusters and use one of the load generator tools that come with Couchbase to create some traffic. (cbworkloadgen in the Couchbase bin folder or cbc-pillowfight that comes with libcouchbase.)

There are several config settings you can play with to optimize throughput, such as increasing batch size, changing the optimistic replication threshold, etc.